# Rotating an image based texture in opengl android

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation

I am drawing an image based texture using opengl in android and trying to rotate it about its center.
But the result is not as expected and it appears skewed.

First screen grab is the texture drawn without rotation and the second one is the one drawn with 10 degree rotation.

[image]

Code snippet is as below:

```
    mViewWidth = viewWidth;//View port width
    mViewHeight = viewHeight;//View port height
    float ratio = (float) viewWidth / viewHeight;
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
    .....
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, 10, 0, 0, 1.0f);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(temp, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, temp, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mRotationMatrixHandle , 1, false, mRotationMatrix, 0);
```

And in shader:

```
....
"  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix*a_position;\n"
....
```

The black area in the first screen grab is the area of GLSurfaceView and the grey area is the area where I am trying to draw the image.

The image is already at origin and I think there is no need to translate before rotating it.

Comment: How do you ensure that the whole thing actually looks square on the screen? Are you calculating the coordinates you draw to compensate for the aspect ratio of the drawing surface? Or are you applying an additional transformation to scale the whole thing? No matter which one it is, I suspect that you have a problem with the order of transformations. I think you're scaling the geometry, then rotating it, instead of the opposite order.

Comment: I have edited the question.I am now using model , view and projection matrices for calculating cordinates.And regarding 'How do you ensure that the whole thing actually looks square on the screen?' , the original image itslef is square and I am calculating the cordinates on the screen on which the image needs to be drawn  , using aspect ration of GLsurfaceview area and image aspect ratio.

Comment: Do you really need all these matrices? At least from what you're showing here, it looks like you're only drawing 2D geometry. Adding all these transformations just makes it a lot more complicated.

Comment: Yes , I am drawing only 2D geometry.I had tried initially with only rotation matrix , but the result was too much skewed and then I thought of including those matrices and the current one is somewhat better than previous result.I am not sure , how to achieve the rotation with aspect ratio maintained as in screen grab 1

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that you're scaling your geometry to adjust for the screen aspect ratio **before** you apply the rotation.

It might not be obvious that you're actually scaling the geometry. But by calculating the coordinates you use for drawing to adjust for the aspect ratio, you are effectively applying a non-uniform scaling transformation to the geometry. And if you then rotate the result, it will get distorted.

What you need to do is apply the rotation before you scale. This will require some reorganization of your current code. Since you apply the scaling before you pass the coordinates to OpenGL, and then do the rotation in the shader, you can't easily change the order. You either have to:

- Apply both transformations, in the proper order, to the input coordinates before you pass them to OpenGL, and remove the rotation from the shader code.
- Apply both transformations, in the proper order, in the shader code. To do this, you would not modify the input coordinates to adjust to the aspect ratio, and pass a scaling factor into the shader instead.

For the first option, applying a 2D rotation in your own code is easy enough, and it looks like you only have 4 vertices, so there is no efficiency concern. Still the second options is certainly more elegant. So instead of scaling the coordinates in your client code, pass a scaling factor as a uniform into the shader. Then, in the GLSL code, apply the rotation first, and scale the resulting coordinates.

Another option is that you build the complete transformation matrix (again based on applying the individual transformations in the correct order), and pass that matrix into the shader.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.It seems I am not understanding peoprly what i am doing , so it was difficult to catch your answer! Anyway inspired by your answer , I got rid of the vertex cordinate re-calculation (values as calculated from image aspect ratio and screen aspect ratio , not directly using (-1,-1) etc) and directly used default vertex (-1,1) and it seems to work.Looks like I was overthinking here!